# Subtract Vector from Every Column of a Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an n x 1 column vector v, and an n x m matrix M. I'm looking for a method to subtract v from every column of M without a loop in Numpy. How can I do this?

I've searched the web and I can't find a method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides searching the web most of the time it is useful to just play around with the arrays and see what works. In you case it is really straight forward:

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 13, 17
v = np.random.random((n, 1))
M = np.random.random((n, m))

res = M - v
```

[This](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is also a good resource to get familiar with the basic concepts of numpy.